# Obtener nombre de archivo tipo var binary guardado en bd sql

Tags: c#

Vengo de nuevo a pedir de su valiosa ayuda, actualmente cargo en mi formulario un nombre genérico de los archivos pdf que previamente he guardado, con una pequeña validación si el campo contiene datos se visualizara un nombre por defecto que yo coloco, pero ahora me solicitan el poder visualizar los nombres reales de cada archivo que en teoría se guardan al momento de almacenarlo en la bd, tengo el siguiente código como podría obtener el nombre del archivo que estoy cargando.

```
  public void Mostrar_Nombre_PDF(TextBox txtCodHisCliP1, Label lblIdHisCli, int Btid,
      TextBox txtIma, Label lblmaEst)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            Buscar_Historial_Clinico_ID(txtCodHisCliP1, lblIdHisCli);
            using (Model.DB_DS_Entities db = new Model.DB_DS_Entities())
            {
                var oImage = db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Find(Convert.ToInt32(lblIdHisCli.Text));
                if (Btid == 1)
                {
                    ms = new MemoryStream(oImage.HISCLI_PDF_1);
                    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                    txtIma.Text = "PDF 1";
                }
                else if (Btid == 2)
                {
                    ms = new MemoryStream(oImage.HISCLI_PDF_2);
                    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                    txtIma.Text = "PDF 2";
                }                    

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmaEst.Text = "NO EXISTE PDF";
            //MessageBox.Show("ERROR: NO EXISTE IMAGEN GUARDADA ", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);               
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Y en donde esta el nombre del archivo?

Comment: El código que pones, guarda el archivo en la bd o saca el archivo de la bd?

Comment: El codigo es para poder sacar la informacion de la bd y como se lo coloco en base a que si encuentra el registro le pongo un nombre "x" pero el cliente quiere que sea el nombre con el cual fue guardado para recordar que imagen debe visualizar.

Comment: Guarda el nombre del fichero original en un campo de la bd

Comment: Tendría que añadir otro campo para poder realizar el guardado del nombre, de tipo varchar?

Comment: Exacto, seria la variante menos conflictiva

Comment: Pero en teoria al guardar el archivo en tipo byte solo se almacena la informacion referente al peso del archivo mas no el nombre verdad?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126325/discussion-between-japv-and-carrobe90).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios intentos y ayuda de compañeros y ustedes, adjunto el código final

```
 public void Guardar_Nombre_PDF(TextBox txtCodHisCliP1, int btpd, String rutaImagen)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Model.DB_DS_Entities db = new Model.DB_DS_Entities())
            {
                if (btpd == 1)
                {

                    Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA pdf = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
                    pdf.HISCLI_N_PDF_1 = rutaImagen;
                    db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d => d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text))
                    .Update(x => new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA() { HISCLI_N_PDF_1 = rutaImagen });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (btpd == 2)
                {
                    Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA pdf = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
                    pdf.HISCLI_N_PDF_2 = rutaImagen;
                    db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d => d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text))
                    .Update(x => new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA() { HISCLI_N_PDF_2 = rutaImagen });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Al final la sugerencia mas viable y fácil de implementar era de crear un campo en la bd de tipo varchar con una longitud de máximo 100 caracteres en donde se almacene directamente el nombre del archivo tipo pdf.